# Material UI responsive grid direction

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I want the container direction as "row" above md size screen and "column" below md size screen?
How can I implement it?

```
<Grid container direction = "row"(in large screens)/direction = "column"(in small screens)>
```

I tried something this.

```
<Grid container classes={gridDirection}>

 gridDirection: {
    direction = "row",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      direction = "column",
    },
  }
```

but it is not working probably because "direction" is a react prop and not a CSS style.
Is there a way to access these react props inside stylesheet file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way and I believe the modern way is to use the sx attribute.   Then let MUI handle the breakpoints for you.
These are the default MUI breakpoints as of writing.

```
xs = extra-small: 0px
sm = small: 600px
md = medium: 900px
lg = large: 1200px
xl = extra-large: 1536px
```

xs and sm are generally considered to be mobile/small tablet. MUI is mobile first, so xs will be set and not overwritten until the size is md or larger in my example below.

```
<Grid container sx={{ flexDirection: { xs: "column", md: "row"} }}>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Fine answer!! =)

If the developer is following the goods MUI practices, and have the breakpoints defined as well, this solution will work!

Comment: Could you share full code?

I can't make it like this.

Answer (score 12):

in MUI v5 you can do it like below:

```xml
<Grid container direction={{xs: "column", md: "row"}}>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use useMediaQuery

```
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

const largeScreen = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.up('md'));

<Grid container direction={largescreen?"row":"column"}>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking there should be at least 3 ways to do it in MUI v5.
with default prop

```
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction={{ xs: 'column', md: 'row' }}
      justifyContent={{ xs: 'center', md: 'flex-end' }}
      alignItems={{ xs: 'center', md: 'flex-end' }}
    >
```

...
with sx props

```
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={0}
          sx={{ flexDirection: { xs: 'column', md: 'row'} }}
        >
```

in theme override

```
MuiGrid: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
            '&.MuiGrid-container': {
              flexDirection:  'column'
              [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                flexDirection:  'row'
               },
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexDirection instead of direction.

```
gridDirection: {
    flexDirection = "row",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      flexDirection = "column",
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least as on date of answering here, Material UI supports `direction` or `flexDirection` attributes with  component, with these attributes supporting responsive value based on breakpoints mapped object passed to it.

For example, in your case, if direction="row" is needed on large screens and direction="column" is needed for small screens, then the prop can be passed in as:
`direction={{xs:'row', lg:'column'}}`, thus letting MUI prop handle it with the Grid element as:

`<Grid container direction={{xs:'row', lg:'column'}}> ... </Grid>`

This is the right style to use it in your code, for this case, in my opinion, though other alternative answers here also work well.

Comment: I tried to use `direction={{xs:'row', lg:'column'}}` but I just get the following error: ```Type '{ xs: string; lg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GridDirection | undefined'.```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **container** *false* for column view and *true* for row view

```
  <Grid container={{ lg: true, sm: false }} 
  ...
  />
```